# merge/join/concatenate hundreds of ts files into one ts file

Tags: ubuntu, video, merge

Downloading a video stream with curl, I ended up with ~400 *.ts files, each about 1MB in size. They are sequentially numbered video1.ts, video2.ts, ...video400.ts. I now need to concatenate them into one file, obviously in the right order (so video10.ts should be followed by video11.ts and not video110.ts).

I've tried to come up with something like "for i in *.ts; do ...." but I just can't figure it out. Also ffmepg and avconv are too complicated for me.

Who knows how to join these 400 files in the right oreder, into a new file? Thx!

Comment: Related:  [Glob with Numerical Order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38317/80216).

Answer (score 7):

Shortest way to concat all .ts into one .ts file : on linux

```
cat *.ts > all.ts
```

Shortest way to concatenate all .ts into one .ts file : on Windows (using cmd)

```
copy /b *.ts all.ts
```

Answer (score 5):

`` filenames="`ls -rt1 $input | tr '\n' '|' | sed '$ s/.$//'`" ``

`ffmpeg -i "concat:$filenames" -c copy out.ts`,

where `$input` is the filename(s) or escaped regexp (e.g., \*.ts).

Comment: Quickest way to concat .ts files with ffmpeg, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers to this question that mislead readers to concatenate the TS files before running ffmpeg are incorrect.  To ensure the audio and video do not fall out of sync during the assembly of the mp4 stream, the poorly documented but important "-f concat" feature of ffmpeg should be used.

```
    delimiterBeforeFileNumber="-"
    ls |egrep '[.]ts$' \
        |sort "-t$delimiterBeforeFileNumber" -k2,2n \
        |sed -r "s/(.*)/file '\1'/" >ts.files.txt

    ffmpeg -f concat -i ts.files.txt -c copy tsw.014.ts.mp4
```

The two preparatory lines of code just create a file containing a list of TS files in this line format, which is used by ffmpeg like a playlist.

```
    file 'seg-37-a.ts'
```

Answer (score 1):

What sort of does the trick:

```
for i in `seq 1 400`; do cat "video$i.ts" >> newvideo.ts; done
```

but now the audio is out of sync by ~0.5s and there are ~0.5s silences every few seconds (presumably when fragments are glued together).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I hope the answer may add value for others.

Based on [this reference](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files), the following script will do the job, assuming `ffmpeg 1.1` and later.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 0 $totalNumberOfTsFiles`; do echo  file "'${i}.ts'" >> Input.txt ; done
/home/hq6/bin/ffmpeg-2.3.3/ffmpeg -f concat -i Input.txt  -c copy output.ts
```

Comment: The entire `for` loop can probably be replaced by something like `seq -f '%g.ts' 0 $totalNumberOfTsFiles` for a similar result with a much cleaner command line.

Comment: James Ivey: If you have a new idea for a different way to solve this problem, don’t try to post it in a comment (and don’t edit it into somebody else’s answer); post it as a new answer (in the “Your Answer” box at the bottom of the page). In case you’ve forgotten what you wanted to submit, [you can review it here](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/702826). Notes: (1) When the output of `ls` is a pipe, it uses `-1` mode automatically. You can see this by running plain `ls` and then `ls | cat`. (2) `ls` sorts its output by name unless you tell it not to, so you don’t need `ls | sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
cat video?.ts video??.ts video???.ts  > out.ts
```

Comment: The duration of `out.ts` will likely be that of the first video.

Comment: You must use `>>` instead of `>`. Otherwise only the last file will be in `out.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

## Best Solution:

Download [TSSplitter](https://www.videohelp.com/software/TSSplitter), click "JOIN" tab and drag all files into the window!

[image]